# codeigniter form base_url no me encuentra la ruta

Tags: codeigniter, formularios, rutas

```
<form id="idlogin"  action="<?= base_url('login/ingresar'); ?>" method="post" role="form" >
```

Login es un controlador  class Login extends CI_Controller 
que tiene una función ingresar

```
function ingresar(){

        print_r($_POST);

        $usuario = $this->input->post("user_login");
        $passw = $this->input->post("pass_login");
```

El tema cuando envió la información me fijo en depurador y el post se hace 
pero busca la ruta http://localhost/Myaplicacion/Login/ingresar y no 
http://localhost/Myaplicacion/aplication/controllers/Login/ingresar

Es decir, no va al controlador ¿A qué se debe si tengo bien la base_url?

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucioné

> Select URIs can be whitelisted from csrf protection (for example API
>   endpoints expecting externally POSTed content). You can add these URIs
>   by editing the ‘csrf_exclude_uris’ config parameter:
>
> $config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array('api/person/add');